# Keep checked items checked while searching in CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I'm having some problems with VB.

I'm trying to create code that will keep the checked items in a `CheckedListBox` while you search through it.  I have an array that stores the names of the checked items, but when you use the `CkeckedListBox.SetCheckedItem()` method, you need to use indices, and those change every time I search in the list box.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim checkeditems(1000) As String
If txtSearch.Text.Length = 1 Then
    For i = 0 To 1000
        If lstVerktyg.CheckedItems.Item(i) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        checkeditems(i) = lstVerktyg.CheckedItems.Item(i)
    Next
End If

Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection("server=" & My.Settings.Host & ";user id=" & My.Settings.User & "; password=" & My.Settings.Pass & "; port=3306; database=" & My.Settings.DB & "; pooling=false")
Try
    Connection.Open()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    Exit Sub
End Try
Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim Query As MySqlCommand
Dim ResultsNumber As Integer = 0
lstVerktyg.Items.Clear()

Query = New MySqlCommand("SELECT `namn` FROM `verktyg` WHERE `namn` LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "%' LIMIT 300;", Connection)
Reader = Query.ExecuteReader()

While (Reader.Read())
    lstVerktyg.Items.Add(Reader.GetString("namn"))
End While

If Reader IsNot Nothing Then Reader.Close()
For i = 0 To 1000
    If checkeditems(i) = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    If lstVerktyg.GetItemChecked(i) Then

    End If
Next
```

What do I do?

Comment: Please show some code.  It's difficult to determine what you may be doing wrong with just the description you've given.

Comment: I've updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can do that.  Let's say you initially fill a `CheckedListBox` control with some items, like this:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange({"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"})
```

Then, you show the form and let the user check whatever items they choose.  Then, when you want to reload the list and retain which items are checked, you can do it like this.  First, you want to create a list of all the checked items:

```
Dim checkedItems As New List(Of Object)(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count)
For Each i As Object In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    checkedItems.Add(i)
Next
```

Then, you can safely clear the items from the `CheckedListBox`:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
```

Then, you can reload the list with refreshed data, for instance:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange({"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"})
```

Then, you can loop through the items in the `CheckedListBox` and check each one if it exists in the saved list of checked items:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If checkedItems.Contains(CheckedListBox1.Items(i)) Then
        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    End If
Next
```

So, to apply that method to your code example, it would look something like this:

```
Dim checkedItems As New List(Of Object)(lstVerktyg.CheckedItems.Count)
If txtSearch.Text.Length = 1 Then
    For Each i As Object In lstVerktyg.CheckedItems
        If i = "" Then Exit For
        checkedItems.Add(i)
    Next
End If

Dim Connection As New MySqlConnection("server=" & My.Settings.Host & ";user id=" & My.Settings.User & "; password=" & My.Settings.Pass & "; port=3306; database=" & My.Settings.DB & "; pooling=false")
Try
    Connection.Open()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    Exit Sub
End Try
Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim Query As MySqlCommand
Dim ResultsNumber As Integer = 0
lstVerktyg.Items.Clear()

Query = New MySqlCommand("SELECT `namn` FROM `verktyg` WHERE `namn` LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "%' LIMIT 300;", Connection)
Reader = Query.ExecuteReader()

While (Reader.Read())
    lstVerktyg.Items.Add(Reader.GetString("namn"))
End While

If Reader IsNot Nothing Then Reader.Close()
For i As Integer = 0 To lstVerktyg.Items.Count - 1
    If checkedItems.Contains(lstVerktyg.Items(i)) Then
        lstVerktyg.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

This only works when the searchfield is empty from the start, but when I delete a character from the field so that the field turns empty, all items turn unchecked.

Comment: I assume that's because you are only adding the items to the `checkedItems` list if the `txtSearch.Text.Length = 1`.  Without knowing the contest, I had no idea why you were checking that, but I assumed you had a good reason for doing so.

Comment: Alright that solved that problem, thank you. But now I have another problem. I have two items in the list, Hammer and Drill. I check both of them and search for H, and then I remove the character. After that only Hammer is checked.